# Running a bash shell script on Windows from within in Notepad++ using NppExec (and Cygwin)

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, notepad++, nppexec

I'm trying to reconstruct how to execute a bash shell `.sh` file on my Windows machine from within Notepad++ using NPPExec. (I've done this successfully before, but my HDD crashed and I don't recall how I did it previously.)

When it was working before, I would run the NPPExec script that called a `.sh` file, and it showed me the console output of the .sh file processing in Notepad++ as if it were processing in cygwin.

This is the example .sh file that I'm trying to get to work:

```
message="Testing"
echo $message
```

This file is located in the root of C:.

**Failed Attempts:**

None of the following three methods work:

- Execute:  `C:\nppexec.sh`

Response:

```
CreateProcess() failed with error code 193:
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

- Execute: `npp_exec C:\nppexec.sh`

Response:

```
message="Testing"
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.    
$message
```

- Adding `#! /bin/bash` to the .sh file as the first line just causes an additional error when npp_exec is run:

  ```
  NPP_EXEC: C:\nppexec.sh
  #! /bin/bash
  CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
  The system cannot find the file specified.
  ```

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to call bash directly:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "command.sh"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error while trying to execute a batch file on windows.

I resolved the problem by executing at first command cmd in console of notepad++, then E:\test.bat

I also have a mksnt installed on my window pc.

by starting at first the bash in console of notepad++, the test shell work well now

```
bash
C:\nppexec.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Run command

`C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd \"$0\" ; echo $@; \"./$1\"; exec bash;" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(FILE_NAME)"`

You can save this command for later use from Run dialog box.

For git bash, change the path like this:

`C:\Progra~1\Git\bin\bash -l -c "cd \"$0\" ; echo $@; \"./$1\"; exec bash;" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(FILE_NAME)"`

Answer (score 1):

With a **single keystroke** I wanted to execute the shell script of the **active Tab** using Cygwin within notepad.

After few hours looking online and experimenting, I finally came up with

1. install NppExec plugin
2. Hit F6
3. paste the following code:

   `//save the file
   NPP_SAVE
   //redirect console output to $(OUTPUT) & silent mode
   npe_console v+ --
   //convert winpath to cygpath
   D:\cygwin64\bin\bash -lc "cygpath \"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)\"
   //execute the file
   D:\cygwin64\bin\bash -lc "$(OUTPUT)"`

Hope that save some time to some people